# Continuous limit for quantized E.M field in free space obtained from periodic boundary condition. I don't get it

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, fourier-transform, quantum-optics

In "The quantum theory of light" from Loudon as in many other books of quantum optic, the approach to have quantization of the free (not in a cavity) electromagnetic field is the following.

We start by imagining a fictive box of volume $V$ in which we apply periodic boundary conditions. Here we work with a simpler example in which we study the propagation of the field around a given axis $z$. Thus we will have $V=L*A$, where $A$ is the section in which we study the light. $L$ is the length associated to axis $z$ in which periodic boundary condition have been applied, with this period 
 being $L$. The quantized electric field then takes this form:

$$E(\mathbf{r},t)=E_T^{(+)}+cc$$
$$E_T^{(+)}=i\sum_{n} \sqrt{\frac{\hbar \omega_{k_n}}{2 \epsilon_0 L.A}} \widehat{a}_{k_n} e^{-i(\omega_{k_n} t-k_n.z)}$$

You can check this on page 141 of the book adapted for the continuum limit they do on page 238.

But if we want to properly describe the field, we must go to the continuum limit. For this purpose the approach is to make $L \rightarrow +\infty$. And they say that it leads to the following field:

$$E_T^{(+)}=i \int_0^{+ \infty} d \omega \sqrt{\frac{\hbar \omega}{4 \pi \epsilon_0 c A}} \widehat{a}(\omega) e^{-i(\omega t - z/c)}$$

Where they defined:

$$\widehat{a}(\omega)=\sqrt{\frac{2 \pi c}{L}}\widehat{a}_{k_n}$$

**I don't understand how they do to get to this**. This is my main question.

**If someone can show me a rigorous derivation of the continuum limit, done starting from periodic boundary condition I would be very happy**

For example, as $L$ has been put to infinity I don't even understand the way the operator $\widehat{a}(\omega)$ is defined...

In some reference they just keep the discrete sum involving $L$. So all their operator have an $L$ dependance. But still, with that they are able to make predictions.

**If we don't do the limit, how to make consistant the fact there is a fictive $L$ dependance in the operators ?** This is my second question.

---

### What I understand of the math behind this problem

As far as I understand, the general philosophy of what is done is to use the fact that the limit of infinite period fourier series is the fourier transform.

Said differently, to make use of the following property.

Let us call $f$ a function. We call $f_L$ the periodized version of $f$ on $[-L/2,+L/2]$ (so in practice it matches the expression of $f$ in this interval, and is periodized outside). We have the following mathematical property:

$$\lim_{L \rightarrow +\infty} f_L(x) = \lim_{L \rightarrow +\infty} \frac{1}{L} \sum_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f_n e^{i k_n x} = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \widehat{f}(k) e^{ikx} dk $$

Where $\widehat{f}(k)$ is the fourier transform of $f$.

But, because they have a behavior in $1/\sqrt{L}$, it is not possible to directly apply this to the problem. Furthermore, as explained before, their definition of the operator $\widehat{a}(\omega)$ doesn't make sense for me (it goes to $0$ for $L\rightarrow +\infty$.

**How to make sense of all this ?**

Comment: "show me a rigorous derivation of the continuum limit, done starting from periodic boundary condition" The rigorous approach doesn't do it this way. See for example the third paragraph, p.2 of [Summers](https://arxiv.org/abs/1203.3991). I wish the physics textbook writers would indicate when they are hand-waving.

Comment: @KeithMcClary I am not totally sure to see which part you refer to ? First, you are talking of page 2 or part 2 ? Maybe his statement is too general for me to understand. But I mean this periodic boundary condition "trick" is so widely used (look at for example https://www.phys.ksu.edu/personal/wysin/notes/quantumEM.pdf ) that there must be a reason of why it works.

Comment: You refer to the book my London.  Is that correct, or did you mean the book by *Loudon*?   If it is the book by Loudon, then I will comment to @StarBucK that that book does not claim to be a textbook.  It is a *very good" intermediate-level monograph.

Comment: @garyp indeed, it is Loudon I made a typo. Which reference do you suggest me that properly does the continuum limit ? Or that directly (without periodic boundary conditions) and properly derives the continuous version of the operator. The thing is that I know in QFT book this kind of things is done but there are many extra considerations linked to the fact they want to later on do non relativistic Q.M. It disturbs me to go to the essential. I would thus like a derivation but for quantum optic purposes.

Comment: I can *suggest* the book by Mandel and Wolf, *Optical Coherence and Quantum Optics*.  I can't say for sure that it will satisfy your concerns, but it is generally a very good book on quantum optics.  In fact, I use *both* Loudon and Mandel.  First Loudon to get an overview and intuition, then Mandel for details.  For me, it's an effective and very satisfying combination.

Comment: @garyp I took a quick look. It appears he does the same, he introduces a quantization volume and use periodic boundary conditions. He says that it is easier to proceed this way and that at the end you just have to make the volume go to infinity. But it this procedure that causes me some troubles.

Comment: @garyp An approximate answer would be to say you need to take $L$ way bigger than the size of your experiment, and such that $c/L << T$ where $T$ is the duration of your experiment (to avoid time periodicity in your description on the duration of the experiment). But I still find disturbing that some quantity seems to depend on $L$ in the description when you do it...

Comment: The issue *might* involve mathematical difficulties in quantum mechanics.  For example the difficulties with non-normalizable wave functions, or unbound operators. This is a *guess* and way beyond my pay grade.  It does sound like a good question for S.E.

Comment: I mean page 2. The rigorous treatment uses the appropriate mathematical tools of functional analysis and operator theory for infinite space. There is no need to consider models with periodic boundary conditions. Even if you could prove the limit rigorously in some sense, I think you would need the advanced mathematical tools to do it.

Comment: I see. Well I think I found a way to properly show that as long as you have an idea of the size of the experiment ($L_0$) and its duration ($T_0$), you can describe all the physics with discrete Fourier series, given that $L>L_{min}$, where $L_{min}=Max(cT_0,L_0)$. The physics will then become independant of your choice of $L$. I will post an answer with this later on. However it doesn't explain the continuous limit part, but at least my second question.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend the book by Chiao and Garrison, they cover this in Appendix A.4.

When quantizing on a finite interval $[-L/2,L/2]$ the basis vectors $u_{k_n}(x) = C e^{ik_nx}$ need to be normalized:
$$
\int_{-L/2}^{L/2} C^2e^{-ik_nx}e^{ik_nx} dx = 1
$$
hence:
$$
1=\int_{-L/2}^{L/2} C^2 dx = C^2 L \iff C = \frac{1}{\sqrt{L}}
$$
Therefore, in your notation:
$$
\lim_{L\to \infty} f_L(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{L}}
\lim_{L\to \infty} \sum_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f_n e^{ik_n x}
$$
To get to the continuum limit, include the mode spacing $\Delta k = 2\pi / L$ in the sum:
$$
\lim_{L\to \infty} f_L(x) =
\lim_{L\to \infty}
\sum_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{\Delta k}{2\pi} \sqrt{L} f_n e^{ik_n x} = \int \frac{dk}{2\pi} \hat{f}(k) e^{ikx}
$$
This is where the substitution:
$$
\sum_k \to L \int \frac{dk}{2\pi}
$$
comes from (Loudon uses frequency, but the steps are the same).